# Axios http call gets canceled everytime even though it works on the browser perfectly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

First time trying axios and reactjs. This is my component called CountryListSideBar:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class CountryListSidebar extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      options: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    let self = this;
    const config = {
      timeout: 10000
    };

    axios.get('https://localhost:5000/country/getAll', config)
      .then(response => {
        console.log("response returned: " + response.data);
        self.setState({ options: response }) ;
      }).catch(error => {
      console.log("returned error: " + error)
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <ul className="list-group left-side-bar">
        {this.state.options.map(function(object) {
          return (
            <li className="nav-item list-group-item list-group-item-success" value={object.id}>
              <a nav-link href="#">{object.name}</a>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    );
  }

}

export default CountryListSidebar;
```

I was using static json and it was working. Then I decided to try Axios. When I type the request address (localhost:5000/country/getAll) on the browser I get the json response in 2 or 3 seconds.

It catches the error in the console.log: "Error: Network Error". And this is what I get in the Network tab of chrome:

```
getAll  (failed)    xhr xhr.js:178  0 B 79 ms
```

Comment: Then it should be something wrong on backend side. Wrong endpoint or probably CORS?

Comment: What's the error on server's logs?